# How to zip a file loaded in memory without saving it to a file?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to build a component in a project that archives files before saving them in the database.

Do you have any algorithm suggestions or do you recommend a 3rd party?

I tried the examples from msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280.aspx, but I whould prefer to archive the content of the file in memory, not to save it first to a file

Comment: You can make the archive and using an **Stream** store it in a **byte[]** column.

Comment: Resource recommendation questions are not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, any approaches you have attempted.

Comment: I tried the examples from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280.aspx, but I whould prefer to archive the content of the file in memory, not to save it first to a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DotNetZip is a very useful library.

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Very simple to use. Just check the given examples.

Comment: DotNetZip is sweet, +1 for the recommendation.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. From the link you suggested :  creating zip files from stream content, saving to a stream, extracting to a stream, reading from a stream

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has included the ability to zip files in .Net 4.5 using the [ZipFile Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx)

It can be accomplished by calling the [CreateFromDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485707.aspx) method if you have a directory of files

Comment: can it be used only if the file is saved in a directory ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib`. It is an [open-source](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) library also available as a [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll/). This also works with Mono.

If you are using .NET 4.5 , then `System.IO.Compression` has `ZipFile` class

Note: If you are using Mono, then ZipFile class won't work because it is not implemented yet.So you have to rely on `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib`.

Comment: I will also try this.

Comment: @CornelMarian All the features you want are available in this library. So , if you try this, you will forget others.This is my experience.